# Salvar diversas variaveis em uma EditText

Tags: java, android

Olá, meu problema está em como salvar diferentes strings que são escritas em uma Editview.

Consigo salvar uma variável a cada vez que um botão é apertado. Mas não sei como salvar uma outra String em uma outra variável, alguem consegue me ajudar?

(Outra dúvida seria como criar variáveis de uma forma automática sem declararas antes)

Comment: Veja a classe *ArrayList*

Answer (score 1):

Para armazenar diversas variáveis, você precisa de uma estrutura para adicionar várias variáveis.

Se você souber o quantidade de entradas que você terá pode usar um Array:

`String[] valores = new String[5] // 5 = o número de "gavetas" que seu Array terá`

Desta forma você pode acessar o conteúdo fazendo `valores[índice]`

Quando você não sabe a quantidade de entradas que terá, você pode usar uma Lista de objetos.

`List<String> minhaLista = new ArrayList<>();`

Desta forma, quando precisar armazenar uma variável, use `minhaLista.add("Minha String");`  e para recuperar o valor use `minhaLista.get(índice)`